# What is a good, free, windows disk wiping utility similar in functionality to DBAN?

Tags: windows, disk-utility

I have an external ESATA drive I want to do more than zero, (I would rather clobber with random data, such as the  [U.S. Department of Defense disk wiping policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_remanence%20%22)), that is free as in GNU/OSS.

#### Short hand requirements

- Windows *only*, x64 *preferred* but not required.
- No linux live-CD
- No virtual OS creation
- Free/OSS

Surely such software exists, or can exist but my google-foo could not locate it.

Perhaps Windows cannot actually do this? I would imagine it could with a non-system drive, at least.

---

edit:

This question is **not** an exact duplicate. The linked question (which I read fully before asking) says to use a linux utility. The linked question recommends two linux utilities, only, in the accepted answer! This question is specifically, clearly, and deliberately is asking for a *windows only* solution, which requires no linux or unix parts. So from my perspective, "exact duplicate" is provably inaccurate. What is the best way to appeal an improperly closed question?

Comment: I agree that this should be un closed! I have the same question

Comment: related/similar: http://superuser.com/questions/86952/disk-wiping-other-than-dban

Answer (score 1):

Use [HDD Low Level Format Tool](http://hddguru.com/software/2006.04.12-HDD-Low-Level-Format-Tool/) and then [Sdelete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443) if you want a random re-write... its not necessary though. You should also run [HDDScan](http://hddguru.com/software/2006.01.22-HDDScan/) afterwards.

If it has to be OSS you can use [Eraser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eraser/)